# Jersey unable to Marshall the data - MIME media type application/json was not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

Jersey unable to marshall the data. I get the following exception.

```
2015-09-28 12:55:03,177 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) A message body writer for Java class net.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and Java type class net.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and MIME media type application/json was not found
2015-09-28 12:55:03,194 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General

2015-09-28 12:55:03,199 SEVERE [com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and Java type class net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:285)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1437)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and Java type class net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.entities.ServiceName, and MIME media type application/json was not found
    ... 29 more
```

**DataConversionServices.java**

```
package net.tds.adm.metasolv.transcon.rs;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.Services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class DataConversionServices {

    @Autowired
    public Services service;

    @GET
    @Path("/getName")
    public Response getName() {
        Response response = Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(service.getName())
                .build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Dependencies

[image]

**ServiceName.java**

```
package net.tds.adm.metasolv.transconv.entities;


public class ServiceName {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>net.tds.adm.metasolv.transcon.rs</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: [Configure the POJOMappingFeature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Jersey will use its own internal JSON providers. These only work with model classes annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

Generally, instead of using the Jersey providers, use the Jackson provider. You configure Jersey to use it by [configuring the POJOMappingFeature](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json.pojo.approach.section)

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

With Jackson, you don't need the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your model classes.

Comment: Show the `ServiceName` class. And how you configured the feature (i.e. web.xml or Java)

Comment: I don't know it works fine for me. If you want me to test your project (or a small version of it that reproduces the problem), I can check it out if you post it on Github. I didn't use Spring though when testing. I wonder if that has anything to do with it

Comment: I think I know the issue, I added all the jersey libraries to one of my project library and imported this into main project, this is not working some how. I added the jersey libraries to the main app, it worked. Thank you for your time